# How to check the existence of a path in Rust 1.1?

Tags: rust

In Rust 1.1, `std::fs::PathExt` is marked unstable; how do I check the existence of a file or directory?

Is there a canonical solution for this or do i have to read the source of `std::fs::PathExt`?

Is there maybe a crate that delivers this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PathExt` is simple wrappers around [`std::fs::metadata`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.metadata.html); if the path doesn’t exist, `metadata` will return an error, so `PathExt.exists()` is a simple `metadata(self).is_ok()`.

Typically you should be using `is_file` or `is_dir` instead, though; they correspond to `metadata(self).map(|m| m.«is_file or is_dir»()).unwrap_or(false)`.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work: src/projects.rs:9:58: 9:59 error: unknown start of token: \u{ab}
src/projects.rs:9         if !metadata(Path::new(expansion_str)).map(|m| m.«is_file or is_dir»()).unwrap_or(false)||

Comment: @xophos, you do understand that `«is_file or is_dir»` is just a placeholder for actual function name, don't you?

Comment: ah sorry i'm very new to rust so i thought it was some strange syntax.